# Installation of NLTK in virtualenv created for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk, python-venv

I installed tensorflow on my mac using anaconda as mentioned in the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#using-conda).

I'm using PyCharm and I selected the correct interpreter where tensorflow is installed (otherwise Im unable to import tensorflow). I would like to import nltk in this environment now. I don't see nltk in this environment. So I activated the virtual env from terminal and did pip install nltk. But it says nltk is already installed. How I can use nltk (or any other package) in the environment I created?

[image]

```
(tensorflow/) MacBook-Pro:~$ pip install nltk

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nltk in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Comment: `conda install nltk`

Comment: or `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<your_username>/Library/Python/2.7/bin`